# Why is orbital angular momentum quantized according to $I= \hbar \sqrt{\ell(\ell+1)}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, lie-algebra, representation-theory

I simply have no idea how this result is found $$I=\hbar  \sqrt{\ell(\ell+1)}.$$ The result seems to just be dumped in textbooks rather than explained. I can get the result that $I_z=\hbar m_j$. Please explain as clearly as possible how this is derived.

Also, any pointers towards any books/videos that may help me learn quantum mechanics would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148421/2451

Comment: That's actually a bit of a thorny problem, but the gist has to be something like, "we get this equation for $\Phi(\phi)$, we can assume $\Phi(\phi) = Z(\cos(\phi))$ because on this range $\cos$ is invertible; that gives the [associated Legendre equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLegendreDifferentialEquation.html) in $z = \cos\phi$, then to get a proper solution we need (at least) $\Phi'(0) = \Phi'(\pi) = 0$, and possibly for other derivatives to also vanish." Those boundary conditions are pretty much the only things that *can* quantize the associated number to $\ell (\ell + 1).$

Comment: ACuriousMind's answer is correct, but is not going to demystify this issue for people who are not fluent in group theory. For a very rough, intuitive, visual argument, see section 14.2.4 of my book Simple Nature: http://www.lightandmatter.com/area1sn.html .

Answer (score 5):

This comes from the [representation theory of the rotation group $\mathrm{SO}(3)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_SU%282%29).

Quantum mechanics takes place in a vector space, and observables are operators on this space. The total amount of angular momentum is obtained from the angular momenta $L_x,L_y,L_z$ about the three axes of space as
$$ L = \sqrt{L_x^2+L_y^2+L_z^2} $$
since that is the length of the vector $\vec L = (L_x,L_y,L_z)^T$.

The representation theory of the rotation group now tells you that the only possible values for $L$ on so-called *irreducible representations*, to which the states with $I = \sqrt{l(l+1)}$ belong, are restricted to $L = \sqrt{l(l+1)}$ with $l$ an integer. You cannot make $L_x,L_y,L_z$ behave as angular momentum operators (i.e. as operators which generate the rotations in the sense that they form the Lie algebra belonging to the rotation group) without $L$ taking these integer values. The proof of this is technical and found e.g. on the Wikipedia page I linked in the beginning, or, in another approach, found in my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/130415/50583).

The prefactor $\hbar = \frac{h}{2\pi}$ for $\sqrt{l(l+1)}$ is found by dimensional analysis and comparing to experimental results.

Comment: It's probably not as general, but there's also the fact that if you're solving Schrodinger's equation for a rotational system you'll end up with Legendre polynomials (or, in general, spherical harmonics), and if you don't quantize $\ell$ you won't get well-behaved solutions.

Comment: Is it not possible to get this result from the Schrodinger equation?

Comment: @zeldredge: Actually, the [spherical harmonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Connection_with_representation_theory)(link to relevant part of the Wiki article) with fixed $l$ are all the irreducible representations of the rotation group, so I believe that is a fully equivalent way if you have a rotationally invariant Hamiltonian.

Comment: Oh, I think you're right. Sorry, my representation theory isn't as good as it could be and I don't have good intuition for how it enters into things.

Comment: @RobChem: It is possible e.g. if you look at the [hydrogen atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom#Mathematical_summary_of_eigenstates_of_hydrogen_atom). You find that the solutions to the angular dependent part, the [spherical harmonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Laplace.27s_spherical_harmonics), exhibit precisely the $l(l+1)$, but there it just kinda falls out of the structure of the solutions with little insight to it. The representation theory is the underlying reason.